C++ | Как конвертировать пользовательские структуры (классы) друг в друга с помощью функций?
Всем привет.
Имеется две шаблонные структуры:
Point2<T>

Vector2<T>

Обе имеют аналогичные поля T x, T y
Ввиду того, что они будут содержать разные функции, то я не хочу представлять Vector2, как Point2 (через typedef).
После моей попытки написать конвертирующие функцию, Возник вопрос, как мне сконвертировать одно в другое (и наоборот).
Моя попытка (код ниже), заранее не имеющая права на жизнь.
template <typename T>
Point2<T> Vector2<T>::ToPoint2() {
    return Point2<T>(x, y);
}

Этот код функционирует и работает, как надо. Но мне нужно описать и такой же в другой структуре, но в таком случае хеддеры, где описаны эти структуры будут включать друг друга, из-за чего будет ошибка, то есть vector2.h будет включать point2.h, а point2.h будет включать vector2.h
Хочу написать именно функции, а не обращаться к операторам типа operator Vector2() const;
Помогите пожалуйста.

Используйте forward declarations в хедерах, а в .cpp включайте полностью, тогда не будет проблем

Попробовал, сработало, но вопрос, а есть ли еще способы? Все таки, если будет потребность написать много функций, то придется и много раз их объявлять

@te1ny ну от циклических зависимостей обычной так избавляются. В идеале их вообще не иметь, изменив дизайн, но надо понимать что вы хотите сделать
